# Variable change without any direct action

Tags: c++, qt

I have wrote an API as defined below. This API is used to find the index of a filename in a file system. The filesystem is coming from an Android device through mtp. What I'm doing is to request a list of files stored on the Android device and compare each file listed to the one I'm looking for 'name2look'

I have created a vector table to store what I'm doing but it's not mandatory. My concerns is that the variable name2look contain the right name I'm looking for "Pictures"

```
uint32_t USBDevice::GetIndexFromName(LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *dev, uint32_t storage,const char *name2look)
{
    uint32_t idx_fold = 1;
    std::vector<MyFileTreeItem*> FSimage;
    LIBMTP_file_t *files;
    LIBMTP_file_t *file;

    std::cout << "NAME : " << name2look << "\n";
    files = this->GetFileAndFolder(dev, storage,0);
    file = files;
    while (file != NULL) {
        MyFileTreeItem* FSitem = new MyFileTreeItem();
        FSitem->filename = file->filename;
        FSitem->index = file->item_id;
        FSitem->FileType = file->filetype;
        FSimage.push_back(FSitem);

        std::cout << "NAME : " << name2look << "\n";
        std::cout << "FS NAME : " << file->filename << "\n";
        if(std::strcmp(file->filename, name2look)==0) {
            std::cout << "FIND IDX : " << file->item_id << "\n";
            return file->item_id;
        }
        file = file->next;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

The Log is showing that the first display 'std::cout' is ok. the variable name is still 'Pictures' but when I ask to display it after in the "while" the variable name2look change and is not the same anymore.

First display
NAME : Pictures
second one in the while
NAME : Martin).mp3
FS NAME : Music

How is it possible to be corrupted ??

The function is called by a Qt C++ code:

```
void MyButtonGroup::buttonClick(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    uint32_t status;
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> itemList;
    uint32_t index = 0;

    if (button->text() == "Create Folder") {        
        itemList = this->MyTree->selectedItems();

        QString str = itemList[0]->text(0);
        char *utf8_text = str.toLatin1().data();
        if(utf8_text != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "A CHERCHER " << utf8_text << "\n";
            index = this->MyDevice.GetIndexFromName(this->dev_id, storage->id, utf8_text);
        }
        else
            index = 0;

        CreateFolderDialog *dialog = new CreateFolderDialog(this->MyTree, this->MyDevice, this->dev_id, this->storage, index);
        dialog->show();
    }
```

utf8_text report the right value.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This *might be* the problem. I am not sure. Check it out.

This line:

```
char *utf8_text = str.toLatin1().data();
```

What does the documentation say `toLatin1()` does? It creates a new `QByteArray` object and then  you call `data()` on that and you get a pointer to character and then **the QByteArray is destroyed at the end of the line because it was TEMPORARY**.

And now you have an invalid pointer to freed memory that you then pass into your function. It probably gets overwritten by the first call to `new()` in your function.

I think you should change it to something like this:

```
QByteArray latin_str = str.toLatin1();
char *utf8_text = latin_str.data();
```

Your name `utf8_text` is weird since you just converted it to Latin1 which isn't UTF8.

Comment: it's seems you are right. as soon as I comment the call to "new", the data is no more corrupted

Comment: @Seb: That is fixing the wrong thing though. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Seb: sorry, forgot this was a QString. Fixing it again.

Comment: Thx. that's perfectly work. I'm looking on how it can be change inside the wrong call... in the called api and not in the caller

Comment: @Seb: It changes because the memory that utf8_text is pointing to has been marked as free to reuse when the `QByteArray` is destroyed at the end of the statement. *Any* call to `malloc()` or `new()` is likely to reuse it and write into it.